# Как сделать чтоб return возвращал responseBody?

Tags: java, android, запрос, get

```
String run() throws Exception {
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://p.com")
                        .build();

                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                            Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                            for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                                System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                            }

                            System.out.println(responseBody.string());
                        }
                    }
                });
                return null;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В андроиде нельзя делать запросы в сеть на главном потоке. Засим система заставляет вас делать это в к-л другом потоке. Без костылей возвращать запрос синхронно, на том же потоке где вы и вызвали код, при этом запрос делая в другом потоке у вас не выйдет. Да и работать будет не всегда, ибо после 5с ожидания на главном потоке система выкинет `ANR` и предложит завершить приложение.

Вывод:

Сделать можно, но в 100% случаев работать не будет и приложение будет зависать на время запроса. Т.е. простой ответ - этого сделать нельзя. Вам надо реагировать на результат запроса именно в `onResponse` и `onFailure` колбэках. Метод же не должен ничего возвращать.